# Escaping asterisks and other special characters in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have a requirement to read a file in, line by line and construct a piped grep statement to eliminate these patterns by using the -v flag, i.e. I have  a file, say *negativelist*, which contains the following patterns:

```
Hello
World
Java
```

Thus, I read this file line by line and construct the piped grep statement as follows to eliminate these patterns from a sample file, *inputfile*

grep -v "Hello" inputfile | grep -v "World" | grep -v "Java"

However, I am facing problems while declaring special characters in the *negativelist*. While I would ordinarily, use grep -v '*' *inputfile* to elimiate all lines containing the asterisk, I can't seem to make this work. Escaping the asterisks with single quotes in the *negativelist* doesn't seem to help. Any thoughts on how I should escape the asterisk so that I am able to eliminate lines containing it, using my current approach of surrounding any line read from the *negativelist* with double quotes?

To clarify, I have the following set of constraints:

- The grep piped string is constructed by a script in the following form:
  grep -v "line1 from *negativelist*" *inputfile* | grep -v "line2 from *negativelist* ... and so on
- Further, this script runs this grep command and stores its output in another file.
- I can only control what goes in between the double quotes, by defining the patterns in the *negativelist*. I cannot change the way the script generates these piped grep statements
- Even thought I get the desired output by executing grep "*" *inputfile* from the command line, simply storing * in the *negativelist* does not produce the desired result of removing all lines containing an asterisk in them.
- Further, defining a pattern such as Hello.*World to eliminate all lines of the form

  Hellotest1World, or

  Hellotest2World

when defined in the *negativelist* doesn't seem to work either possibly possibly the asterisk is not escaped correctly. The following statement on the command line works correctly: grep -v "Hello.*World" *inputfile*
, i.e. it correctly eliminates all lines containing Hello followed by any character(s) in between followed by World

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fgrep` instead of just `grep`, that performs an exact match without expanding anything.

Ex:

```
$ cat /tmp/a
aaa
zzz
eee
***
rrr
ttt
yyy

$ fgrep -v -e 'aaa' -e '*' -e zzz -e yyy /tmp/a
eee
rrr
ttt
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Assuming I can't use fgrep as the script which constructs these piped statements is not something I control, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Post edited. What do you control ? `grep` can be use like this too : `grep '\*'`

Comment: The script which generates the piped grep statement actually surrounds each line from the *negativelist* with double quotes. Thoughts on how I should declare the asterisk in the *negativelist* given this constraint?

Comment: I only control the contents of the *negativelist*. So I will have to escape the asterisk in some form.

Comment: You can run `sed -i 's@\*@\\*@g' FILE` to escape all '*'

Comment: Use fgrep's -f option to specify a file containing the list of things to match (or not match, in this case), instead of several -e.  Also note that fgrep (or the equivolent grep -F) does not treat '*' in any special way.  It's just a character.  Fixed strings.